# Spring Batch Multi Threading with Partitioner

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch

Is there any issue if we use Partitioner along with multi threaded steps ?

My idea is that if I have to process huge records from 2 different database tables , then I use partitioner to split the tables and then each step with Step scope will execute queries against a table  in a multi thread manner ? I am planning to use `JDBCPagingItemReadr` and `JDBCBatchItemWriter`

Comment: Did you face any issue with what you are proposing?

Comment: not really..everything looks good...except that sometimes the final commit to the database is not matching with commit-interval/chunk size...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience I don't see any problem with that, as the workers in partitioned Spring Batch are nothing but Steps themselves. So nothing prevents you from doing so.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning).

But you should keep in mind whether you are going to launch your workers on the same machine or not. And thus if you will gain something from multithreading you workers or not.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you... I am not seeing any issues from my testing..also, I am using the Partitioner approach and there will not be any workers....